# XSLT: output condition

Tags: xslt

I have some values:

```
//property[@name='bla1']/value
//property[@name='bla2']/value
//property[@name='bla3']/value
```

I need to change paramet "is-active" to 0, if they are all equal to zero or empty.

if bla1=bla2=bla3="0 or empty" then "is-active"=0, other 1

I find example, but i don't know how to use this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="is-active">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="...">0</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
```

Pls, help me.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you are looking for is this...

```
<xsl:when text="//property[@name='bla1']/value='0'
                and //property[@name='bla2']/value='1'
                and //property[@name='bla3']/value='2'">
```

Note, you do not necessarily need the `//` in front of the **property** element. If your current context was positioned on the parent of all the **property** elements you could leave them out

```
<xsl:when text="property[@name='bla1']/value='0'
                and property[@name='bla2']/value='1'
                and property[@name='bla3']/value='2'">
```

Alternatively, you could use a key to get the values

```
<xsl:key name="bla" match="property/value" use="../@name" />
```

Then you could write this

```
<xsl:when text="key('bla', 'bla1')='0' 
                and key('bla', 'bla2')='1'
                and key('bla', 'bla3')='2'">
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2 I would do it like this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="is-active" 
select="
if (every $i in //property[@name=('bla1','bla2','bla3')]/value satisfies $i=0)
then 0
else 1
"/>
```

or if you want to use xsl:choose:

```
<xsl:attribute name="is-active">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="every $i in //property[@name=('bla1','bla2','bla3')]/value satisfies $i=0">0</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
```

you probably also need a more generic way to select the value nodes, so you can use something like

```
//property[matches(@name,'bla')]/value
```